# "You gotta do what you gotta do" and similar expressions

Tags: expressions, terminology, sentence-patterns

> You gotta do what you gotta do.
>
> It's there because it's there.
>
> Stuff, because stuff.

Does this pattern of expression have a name? Existential assertion, maybe?

Comment: You might add, "It is what it is". I am pretty sure this one started in respectable Buddhism, but last summer I heard it used by someone of 22-but-stuck-at-fourteen to mean, "You have to put up with everything I do".

Comment: @DavidPugh: I hear this crap everyday from theists.

Comment: Which crap? "It is what it is" or "You have to put up with everything I do"? Moi, I've never heard a theist say "It is what it is". I should be interested in hearing you expand on your experiences with these phrases and theists. Don't worry, I'm not one!

Comment: I must defend Descartes; the Cogito is the entirely true observation that you cannot claim not to exist, because if you do, who is doing the claiming? By extension, we cannot imagine being dead, because then who is doing the imagining? But I do agree, people use it as a silly jingle. Persil Washes Whiter, I think therefore I am, Beanz Meanz Heinz. You know "The Australian Philosophers' Song"? _Rene Descartes was a drunken fart, I drink therefore I am_.

Comment: Well, ever since I developed back problems from too much concentrated desk work, my motto is *Cogito Ergonomic Sum*.

Comment: These various statements remind me of the reflexive property of equality in mathematics: "For every real number x, x = x."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two could be called [truisms](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/truism): "an undoubted or self-evident truth; especially one too obvious for mention"

However, "because" has [taken on a new life on the Internet](http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2013/11/english-has-a-new-preposition-because-internet/281601/) lately, as a "prepositional-because." Because Internet slang.

Comment: Would my proposed term be considered wrong then?

Comment: @VatsalManot, I would call prefer "*tautological* assertion" maybe...or, corresponding to "existential" ....***epistemological assertion***